# Establish gtest version

Tags: c++, linux, googletest

How do I know which version of Gtest is being used in the project I'm working with? I'm working on a linux platform.

Comment: are you infusing or linking?

Comment: What files of gtest do you see within your project? Can you find the folder where gtest/gtest.h is in?

Answer (score 4):

The source code of `libgtest` or `libgtest_main` libraries doesn't contain special functions which allow recognize their version (something like `GetGTestVersion ()` or something else).
Also header files doesn't have any defined identifiers (something like `GTEST_VERSION` or something else).
So you can’t check version of `Google C++ Testing Framework` at runtime inside user code.

But maintainers provide as part of the framework special script [scripts/gtest-conf](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/source/browse/trunk/scripts/gtest-config.in) which:

```
...
provides access to the necessary compile and linking
flags to connect with Google C++ Testing Framework, both in a build prior to
installation, and on the system proper after installation.
...
```

Among other things this script has several options which connected with version:

```
...
Installation Queries:
...
--version the version of the Google Test installation

Version Queries:
--min-version=VERSION return 0 if the version is at least VERSION
--exact-version=VERSION return 0 if the version is exactly VERSION
--max-version=VERSION return 0 if the version is at most VERSION
...
```

The script also contain usage example of it:

```
Examples:
gtest-config --min-version=1.0 || echo "Insufficient Google Test version."
...
```

It means that user can test version of the framework in build time using script `gtest-config`.

**Note**:

The script `gtest-config` get actual version of the framework during configuration through variables declared in [configure.ac](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/source/browse/trunk/configure.ac).

```
...
AC_INIT([Google C++ Testing Framework],
        [1.7.0],
        [googletestframework@googlegroups.com],
        [gtest])
...
```

And after calling `autoconf` the following identifiers inside `configure` file populated:

```
...
# Identity of this package.
PACKAGE_NAME='Google C++ Testing Framework'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='gtest'
PACKAGE_VERSION='1.7.0'
PACKAGE_STRING='Google C++ Testing Framework 1.7.0'
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='googletestframework@googlegroups.com'
PACKAGE_URL=''
...
# Define the identity of the package.
PACKAGE='gtest'
VERSION='1.7.0'
...
```

As far the framework compiled with option [AC_CONFIG_HEADERS](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.65/html_node/Configuration-Headers.html) this identifiers stored into file `build-aux/config.h` and availiable for user at compile time.

Comment: And when using CMake.. :|

Answer (score 1):

The file CHANGES, in the gtest home directory, contains a gtest version number.

Answer (score 0):

If you have cloned the [official repo](https://github.com/google/googletest) you can check the latest Git commit inside Google Test's directory (using for example `git log -n 1` or `git rev-parse HEAD`) and compare it with the list of [released versions](https://github.com/google/googletest/releases).

In my case, the commit hash is ec44c6c1675c25b9827aacd08c02433cccde7780, which turns out to correspond to release-1.8.0.